# Why am I getting an NSRangeException when asking my table view to scroll to top?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I am using a subclassed tableView made by someone else and it comes with a method `loadObjects` that causes the tableView to repopulate its cells, however it doesn't tell the table view to return to the top after the repopulation. I tried to implement this feature with:

```
- (void)loadObjects{
    [super loadObjects];
    [self.tableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0] atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionTop animated:YES];
}
```

However once `loadObjects` is called (when the table view wants to initially load), i get the following exception:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: 
'-[UITableView _contentOffsetForScrollingToRowAtIndexPath:atScrollPosition:]: 
row (0) beyond bounds (0) for section (0).'
```

I transferred the line I wrote that scrolls the table view to the top to another custom method that is called whenever I pressed a button, and it worked totally fine, so there is a problem in my overwriting of `loadObjects`. Does anyone understand the exception that was thrown?

Comment: Depends on what your [super loadObjects] is doing. It seems that there are no rows when you try to scroll, thus the error trying to scroll to the 1st (index 0) row. Normal practice to to refresh the data model, then call reloadData to update the UI. So, you don't actually rely on loadObjects to repopulate the cells, just the underlying data.

Comment: while loading the view your table view is nil, means there is no rows in table view,thats why you are getting exception.

Answer (score 3):

Test reloading the tableview before calling scrollToRowAtIndexPath.

```
[self.tableView reloadData];
```

Answer (score 3):

As some of the commenters pointed out, you'll see this error when attempting to scroll to an index path that does not exist (according to the results of numberOfSectionsInTableView and numberOfRowsInSection).

So the fix is to not attempt to scroll to a non-existent index path. You might achieve this fix by changing the order in which this method is called, relative to loading your data (as the commenters suggested), or by some other means (e.g. changing the way you compute which index path to scroll to, or only scrolling conditionally if the index path is sure to exist).